# Android - Update time format(12/24 hour format) of TextClock in a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a recyclerview, which one of the view type is TextClock. When the system time format(12/24 hour format) is changed, the textClock does not update. The textClock's format is only updated after the activity restart.

Question is:

Is textClock suppose to update itself when system time format changes? Seems that there is a FormatChangeObserver inside textClock implementation.

If not, is there a way to update it?

Will the act of putting a textClock inside a recyclerView messes up its behavior?

Much Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it show current time and define your time format..

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tvClock.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a", Locale.US).format(new Date()));
            someHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }, 10);
```

Comment: Not working. Why setText is needed if TextClock class already provided methods on customizing time format? Even if no time format is set, it will use the system's current text format.